# i can't select any item on my terminal using inquirer python

Tags: python, terminal, cursor, inquirer

**the cursor is not moving and i can just press enter in terminal**

i want to create a menu in my terminal and i want to select items by pressing up and down.
i used inquirer and console-menu.
even when i use this inquirer documentation example of list:

```
import inquirer
questions = [
            inquirer.List('size',
            message="What size do you need?",
            choices=['Jumbo', 'Large', 'Standard', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Micro'],
              ),
            ]
answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
print(answers)
```

output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7odGC.png)

when i press enter:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfYAn.png)

Comment: Does our terminal emulator (ex: iTerm, vscode-builtin-terminal, cmd, powershell) support key inputs other than Enter or basic typing keys? What I mean by this is your terminal might not support arrow keys.